# Dynamically creating options for selectbox using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am dynamically setting the values for a select box using java script

```
var dropDwnObj = document.getElementById("workingBranchCodeId");
dropDwnObj.options.length = 0;
var anOption = document.createElement("OPTION");
dropDwnObj.options.add(anOption) ;

for(var i = 0; i < jsonResult.subLocationList.length; i++) {
  var anOption = document.createElement("OPTION");
  dropDwnObj.options.add(anOption) ;
  if(selValue == jsonResult.subLocationList[i].displayKey) {
    anOption.innerHTML = jsonResult.subLocationList[i].displayValue;
    anOption.value = jsonResult.subLocationList[i].displayKey;
  }
}
```

How can I make this value as the selected value for the select box? currently it is coming like an option but i want this option to be the selected one for the select box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please set select box as multiple selection using **multiple** attriute like below

```
<select multiple>
</select>
```

and set selected attribute is true for options like below

```
anOption.selected = true;
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hfk35p2L/)

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

dropDwnObj.options["your option"].selected = true;

Answer (score 0):

> anOption.selected = true;

worked for me